# La misma función con el mismo parámetro me devuelve resultados distintos

Tags: php

Uso una pequeña función para calcular hace cuanto tiempo se ha hecho un comentario. Esta función recibe la fecha y en función a ello me devuelve un string.

```
function hace_cuanto_comentario ($respuestas) {

    $fecha = $respuestas;

    $hoy = getdate();
    $meses = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio','julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre','noviembre','diciembre'];

    $minuto = $hoy['minutes'];
    $hora = $hoy['hours'];
    $day = $hoy['mday'];
    $mes = $hoy['mon'];

    if ($hoy['hours'] <= 9) {
        $hora = "0" . $hoy['hours'];
    }

    if ($hoy['minutes'] <= 9) {
        $minuto = "0" . $hoy['minutes'];
    }

    if ($hoy['mon'] <= 9) {
        $mes = "0" . $hoy['mon'];
    }

    if ($hoy['mday'] <= 9) {
        $day = "0" . $hoy['mday'];
    }

    $fecha_total_actual = $hoy['year'] . "-" . $mes . "-" . $day . " " . $hora . ":" . $minuto;
    $fecha_total_actual = new DateTime($fecha_total_actual);
    $fecha_apertura = substr($fecha,0,16);
    $fecha_apertura = new DateTime($fecha_apertura);
    $anyo_apertura = substr($fecha,0,4);
    $mes_apertura = substr($fecha,5,2);
    $dia_apertura = substr($fecha,8,2);
    $hora_apertura = substr($fecha,11,2);
    $minuto_apertura = substr($fecha,14,2);
    $interval = date_diff($fecha_apertura, $fecha_total_actual);
    $dia_intervalo = substr($interval->format('%R%a'),1,strlen($interval->format('%R%a')));
    $hora_intervalo = $interval->format('%H');
    $minutos_intervalo = $interval->format('%I');

    $devolver = "";

    if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo < 1) {
        $devolver = "Ahora";
    } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo == 1) {
        $devolver = "Hace " . substr($minutos_intervalo,1,2) . " minuto";
    } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo < 10 AND $minutos_intervalo > 1) {
        $devolver = "Hace " . substr($minutos_intervalo,1,2) . " minutos";
    } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $hora_intervalo == 0 AND $minutos_intervalo < 60 AND $minutos_intervalo >= 10) {
        $devolver = "Hace " . $minutos_intervalo . " minutos";
    } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $dia_apertura == $day) {
        $devolver = "Hoy a las " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura ;
    } else if ($dia_intervalo == 0 AND $dia_apertura == $day-1) {
        $devolver = "Ayer a las " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura;
    } else if ($dia_intervalo == 1 AND $dia_apertura == $day-1) {
        $devolver = "Ayer a las " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura;
    } else {
        $devolver = $dia_apertura . " " . $meses[$mes_apertura-1] . " " . $anyo_apertura . " " . $hora_apertura . ":" . $minuto_apertura;
    }

    return $devolver;
}
```

El parámetro de entrada en este caso es la fecha `2017-07-09 20:52:39`, con lo que me debería de devolver `Hace X minutos`. Sin embargo en un sitio me devuelve el resultado correcto y en otro me devuelve la hora.

¿Cómo es esto posible? He verificado que la función sea la misma, el dato de entrada el mismo...de hecho puedo pasaros el enlace porque tengo con `echo` de PHP mostradas las fechas de entrada a la función.

Aclarar que esto sólo me pasa en la web, en local no. Las tablas de la base de datos son correctas e iguales.

Comment: ya chequease si el error no es provocado por el hosting en el que publicaste la pagina? Teniendo en cuenta que el error no te sale en local. Puedes preguntar a algún administrador del hosting que utilizas, para tu web.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo generar estos errores de DateTime son provocados por el formato de la fecha.

El error no te ocurre en local debido a que tu base de datos utiliza un formato de fecha distinto al del servidor o hosting en el cual almacenaste tu pagina web.

Para obtener el formato de fecha de la Base de Datos del hosting puedes utilizar esto.

> MySQL

```
SELECT now();
```

Si al corregir el formato el problema persiste puedes pedir ayuda a tus proveedores de servicio. Probablemente sea un error interno del hosting, o que la versión de **PHP** que utilizas en local no sea la misma que la del servidor. Esto podría ser otro factor.

Espero te haya sido de ayuda.